# Simulating interfaces when unsupported by a language

Tags: oop, interface, simulate

Is there a way to form pseudo interfaces when these aren't directly supported by an OOP language?

Comment: Any specific language that you're thinking of?

Comment: You have to tell what you've got to work with.

Comment: The language is the version of unrealscript provided with unreal engine 1 (released in '98 or '99). It's a mix of C, Java and other influences and supports inheritance, accessors but not interfaces which is probably a more modern concept. http://unreal.epicgames.com/UnrealScript.htm

Comment: How are interfaces a more modern concept than Java, which has interfaces (and had them in 1998)?

Comment: Apologies, I assumed that was the case and wasn't familiar with Java then and even less so with interfaces. Perhaps the designers of this language didn't see the use for them at the time.

Answer (score 2):

Does it have virtual functions?  An interface is nothing more than a base class with nothing but virtual functions, either without any body, or with a stub that throws an error if the base class version is used.

Comment: Functions can be overridden by an inheriting class but different signatures are unsupported (function "blah" can only appear once). Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: @James: That sounds like an issue with "overloading", not "simulation of interfaces".  It's trivial to make up unique names for the different signatures though.

Comment: Yes overloading isn't possible as you say. But having a common interface while avoiding inheritance would be useful. I was thinking along the lines of using an instance attribute to play the role of middle man. I haven't given this enough thought though and perhaps it would prove unpractical.